# data-add-back-btn does not display for some pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

i've been using data-add-back-btn to make user go back to previous page.I put at all pages that needed. But the problem is, why some pages have the back button but some didn't.

```html
<div data-role="page" id="MregisteredClassesDetails" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

I read some of the stack question, there is plugin where we can use for all pages and **add data-add-back-btn="false"**. but where should i put the code below? in every page? can someone give me an example how to used it with calling from html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
   $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
 });    
</script>
```

Comment: at last i add manually the back button using <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>

Comment: Where did you try to add the script? You should actually add this script BEFORE you add the jquery mobile javascript.